# Approximate sum by an integral: valid or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let:

$$S_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n \mathrm{e}^{n f(i/n)} g(i/n)$$

$$I_n = \int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{nf(x)}g(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are smooth functions (assume they are differentiable up to any order required), $g(x) > 0$, and $n$ is a positive integer.

Note that the sum looks like a Riemann sum, but not quite, because there is an $n$ in the exponent.

Prove or disprove, that $R_n = |(S_n - c I_n) / S_n| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, for some constant $c$ that may depend on $f,g$ and/or its derivatives, but does not depend on $n$. If true, find the value of $c$ and characterize how fast $R_n$ decays as $n$ increases; is it exponentially fast?

Comment: Only small neighborhoods near the points where $f$ attains its maximal value really matter. If the maximum is attained at some inner point, you are fine with $c=1$. If it is attained only at endpoints, then the computation of $c$ is a bit more complicated. The question about the speed of convergence is more delicate. It depends on many factors but is rarely exponential (though it may be; say, if  $g(x)=1$, $f(x)=x-x^2$). With finite smoothness you'll normally get just a power decay.

Comment: @fedja I have some very specific functions in mind, but I do not want to meddle this post in too much details. What kind of techniques are available so that I prove these things? Are there some general conditions under which $R_n$ decays exponentially? Oh, you can assume that the max of $f(x)$ occurs in the interior.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exponential decay is a very rare case. I'd rather prefer to see the functions you have in mind and try to figure out what rate I can guarantee for them than to try to find the weakest assumptions under which the decay is exponential.

Comment: There is one general thing I can say though: if $f,g$ are analytic in a neighborhood of $[0,1]$ and  $f$ attains its global maximum only at interior points, then you are fine. This condition can be relaxed a bit, but, alas, not by much.

Comment: @fedja Can you offer a proof of these last statements? Why is analycity required?

Comment: Yes, I can. But will it be enough for you? If it will, I'll post a detailed explanation today or tomorrow. The trickery consists of the Poisson summation formula and shifting the contour to bound the Fourier transform. It is the second part that requires analyticity. I haven't attempted a proof that analyticity is necessary for the exponential decay in all cases, but it is possible to show that no weaker "natural" assumption will suffice. However, if your functions are, indeed, analytic, then why should you care, and if they are not, the chance that there is some non-generic effect is slim..

Comment: @fedja Thanks. My $f$ and $g$ are analytic. If you offer a proof for this case that would be enough for me. Strange that this is isn't in textbooks (I looked around and couldn't find it).

Comment: @fedja Oh, note that my $f$ and $g$ are analytic *over a restricted domain*. They are not entire. So the contour manipulations should not be too extreme.

Comment: Only analyticity near the points of global maximum is really required (plus the fact that the global maximum does not occur at the endpoints). OK, I'll post the details today when I have time :-)

Comment: @fedja Thank you. I look forward to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**The main observation:**

Let $f,g$ be analytic in the disk $\{|z|\le 2\delta\}$ and real on the interval
$(-2\delta,2\delta)$. Assume that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)<0$ for $0<|x|<2\delta$. Let $\psi$ be any $C^2$-smooth function on $\mathbb R$ such that $\psi\equiv 1$ on $(-\delta,\delta)$ and $\operatorname{supp}\psi\subset(-2\delta,2\delta)$. Let $n$ be a large integer and let $\Lambda$ be any arithmetic progression with step $1/n$. Put $F_n(x)=\psi(x)g(x)e^{nf(x)}$. Then
$$
\frac 1n \sum_{x\in\Lambda}F_n(x)-\int_{\mathbb R}F_n(x)\,dx=O(e^{-cn})
$$
with some $c>0$.

**Proof:**

By the Poisson summation formula, the absolute value of the left hand side is bounded by
$
\sum_{y\in n\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}}|\widehat F_n(y)|
$
where $\widehat F_n(y)=\int_{\mathbb R}F_n(x)e^{-2\pi i yx}\,dx$. Thus, our aim is to estimate the Fourier transform of $F_n$. Since we want to bound an infinite sum, it will be more convenient to get a uniform bound for the Fourier transform of $F_n''$ outside $[-n,n]$, which will give us an extra factor $1/y^2$ when passing to $F_n$ itself. Notice that $F_n''=G_ne^{nf}$ where $G_n$ is continuous, supported inside $(-2\delta,2\delta)$ and analytic in $\{|z|<\delta\}$. Also $|G_n|\le Cn^2$.

Since $f$ attains its strict maximum at the origin and is analytic in a neighborhood, there exist $a>0$, $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $f(z)=-2az^{2k}+\text{higher order terms}$ and the first term dominates in some disk $\{|z|\le 2\Delta\}$. In particular, $|f(z)|\le 3a|z|^{2k}$ when $|z|\le 2\Delta$ and $\Re f(z)\le -a|z|^{2k}$ when $|z|\le 2\Delta$ and $|\Im z|\le \frac \pi{8k}|\Re z|$, say. Now take the integral defining the Fourier transform of $F_n''$ with $y\ge n$ and shift the contour of integration to the one going from $-\infty$ to $-\Delta$ to $-\Delta-\frac\pi{8k}\Delta i$ to $\Delta-\frac\pi{8k}\Delta i$ to $\Delta$ to $+\infty$.

Now just notice that $e^{nf(z)}e^{-2\pi i zy}$ is bounded by $e^{-cn}$ everywhere on the new contour. If is obvious for all pieces except the bottom horizontal one because $\Re f$ is negative and separated from $0$ there. However on the bottom horizontal piece we have
$$
\Re[nf(z)-2\pi i yz]\le n|f(z)|-2\pi \frac\pi{8k} y\Delta
\\
\le \left[3a(2\Delta)^{2k}-2\pi \frac\pi{8k}\Delta\right]n
$$
for $y\ge n$ and we can always make $\Delta>0$ smaller, if needed, to ensure that the expression in the brackets is negative. The pre-factor $G_n$ is $O(n^2)$ everywhere on the contour, so it does not affect this estimate too much.

The rest should be more or less clear (take an appropriate partition of unity and blah-blah-blah) but feel free to ask questions if you meet any difficulty :-) .

Comment: Thanks! I have to digest this. Any chance of looking into the case where the max of $f$ occurs at $0$ or $1$? In this case we probably need a proportionality constant between the sum and the integral that is $\ne 1$.

Comment: @becko Indeed. I corrected. I suspect there are more stupid misprints though :-)

Comment: I do not understand how you bound the integrand in the new contour, from $-\infty$ to $-\Delta$, and from $\Delta$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Turns out I now have a case where the max of $f$ occurs at an endpoint. If you need to know, my $f$ is a Gaussian, and the mean is now at $0$ (before it was between $0$ and $1$. Will I lose the exponential decay in this case? I assume the conclusion in this case does not depend on $g$, correct?

Comment: @becko We have a cutoff $\psi$, remember? So $-\infty$ is actually $-2\delta$ and we have assumed that $f<0$ on $(-2\delta,2\delta)$ except at $0$. If your $f$ and $g$ are both **even**, you still can pretend that you integrate between $-1$ and $1$ and have the exponential decay if you introduce the extra factor $1/2$ for the $0$ endpoint in your Riemann-type sum. If $g$ is not even, you may be out of luck; I have to check.

Comment: I know that $f<0$ on $(-2\delta , 2\delta)$, $x\ne0$, but nothing precludes $f$ from getting arbitrarily close to $0$ even if $x\ne0$. That's why I'm not sure about the bounding from $-2\delta$ to $-\Delta$.

Comment: Also, $f$ is **not** Gaussian. That was a mistake, sorry. Let me see if I can formulate the problem more better to see what kind of generalization we can do if the max occurs at the endpoint. I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: @becko A negative continuous function on a compact set is separated from $0$, isn't it?

Comment: True. Thanks! I'll get back to you on the endpoint issue.

Comment: Can we compute the proportionality constant between the sum and the integral in general, even if the max of $f$ is at an endpoint?

Comment: @becko Yes, we can. Let's say $f$ attains its maximum at $0$ (and $0$ only). If $f'(0)=0$, then it is still $1$. Otherwise it is the same as for $f(x)=f'(0)x$, $g(x)=1$, as M.Dus heas already observed. However the convergence can be slow now. If not a secret, what are you really after with all that?

Comment: I am trying to solve [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/275911/16615) by approximating it with [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/275562/16615).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken,
take $f:x\mapsto x$ and $g:x\mapsto 1$.
Then, $(S_n-I_n)/S_n=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{e}^n}{n}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{e}-1}-\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}-1}+\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}\frac{\mathrm{\mathrm{e}^{n+1}}-1}{\mathrm{e}-1}}$, which converges to $\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: You are correct. I modified the question. $I_n$ needs to be multiplied by a constant so that it approaches $S_n$ (I think). Please don't delete this answer because it is a good example. And sorry for modifying the question.

Comment: Hum, I think that should be true for polynomials, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Anyway, here is a counter-example (with a non-polynomial function):
Take $f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{x}=g(x)$.
Then, $S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum\mathrm{e}^{n\mathrm{e}^{k/n}}\mathrm{e}^{k/n}$, so $S_n\geq \mathrm{e}^n$.
However, $I_n=\frac{1}{n}(\mathrm{e}^{n\mathrm{e}}-\mathrm{e}^n)$, so that $I_n/S_n$.
Then, even with a constant $c$, you get $(S_n-cI_n)/S_n$ converges to $1$.

Comment: $(1/n)\mathrm e^{n\mathrm e} / \mathrm e^n \rightarrow \infty$, so I dont your understand your proof. Can you add some steps? Maybe add it into your answer. If you keep coming up with counterexamples, eventually we'll hit on something true :P

Comment: No you're right, that was a mistake. I thought about it and the constant $c$ should be related to the derivative of $f$, somehow... though it is not easy to find the right one.
I'm sorry for my last post anyway.

Comment: I've thought about your question a little bit. Fedja's answer is really interesting, but in the case where the maximum is not in the interior, you do have to take a constant $c$. I tried a little bit to play with some functions. I took $f$ increasing and $g=1$ and I think that $S_n$ is equivalent to $\frac{\mathrm{e}^{f'(1)}}{\mathrm{e}^{f'(1)}-1}\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{e}^{nf(1)}$, while $I_n$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{f'(1)}\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{e}^{nf(1)}$, but I don't have a formal proof.
That should give us the $c$.

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately, when the maximum is at an endpoint, the exponential decay of $R_n$ is out of question more often than not (say, for $f(x)=-x^2$ and $g(x)=1$ you still have $c=1$ but the convergence is no better than the typical convergence of the left Riemann sum to the integral ($R_n=O(1/n)$ or something like that). That's why I didn't try to address this case in the hope that the OP doesn't really need it.

Comment: Uhm, I suspected it should be similar to Laplace's saddle-point method, where if the max lies on an end-point, you need to include a factor of $1/2$ in the estimate... But I did not think it would affect convergence ....

Comment: @becko The problem with the endpoint is that you'll have to start the contour right there and won't be able to bypass the maximum on the ascent and the descent like I did. That will result in the usual Laplace asymptotics along the imaginary axis as the main term, and that one is just a series in inverse powers.