# Asymptotic form of the eigenvalues / eigenfunctions of a Fredholm equation

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, eigenvalues, integral-operators

Consider the kernel:
$$k(x,y,\xi) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{y+a}} \exp \left(-\frac{\xi^2}{y+a }\right)$$

I am trying to find the asymptotic form of the solutions to the following homogeneous Fredholm equation of the second kind:

$$K_\epsilon [u_\epsilon] (x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_0^1 k\left(x,y, \frac{x-y}{\epsilon} \right) \mathrm d y = \lambda_\epsilon u_\epsilon (x)$$

for small $\epsilon > 0$. That is, I want to find asymptotic series of the form:

$$\lambda_\epsilon  = \lambda_0 + \lambda_1\epsilon + \lambda_2 \epsilon^2 + \dots$$
$$u_\epsilon (x) = u_0 (x) + u_1(x)\epsilon + u_2(x)\epsilon^2 + \dots$$

following the approach of Refs. [1,2]. Although [2] makes the assumption that the kernel is symmetric (my kernel does not satisfy this) I am not sure why this is needed so I tried to apply the method anyway. Eventually [2] finds $\lambda_0 = 1, \lambda_1 = 0$, transforming the problem into the solution of a Sturm-Liouville problem:

$$L[u_0] = \lambda_2 u_0, \quad u_0(0) = u_0(1) = 0$$

where $L[f] = (p(x)f'(x))' + q(x)f(x)$ with

$$p(x) = \int_0^\infty k(x,x,\xi) \xi^2 \mathrm d \xi, \quad 
q(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial^2 k(x,x,\xi)}{\partial y^2} \xi^2 \mathrm d \xi $$

I obtain $p(x) = (x+a)/2$ and $q(x) = 0$, which in turn implies that $u_0$ must be a linear combination of modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind, which cannot satisfy the boundary conditions $u_0(0) = u_0(1) = 0$ non-trivially.

I have reasons to believe that this result is incorrect. I need to confirm if my approach is sound or not, or where is my mistake, ultimately finding the correct asymptotic expansion.

Note that I am only interested in the first few terms of the expansion. Specifically I am happy with obtaining $\lambda_2$, $u_0$ and $u_1$.

[1] *Malinovskii, Ju.G.*, [**Asymptotic expansion of the solutions of integral equations with $\delta$-form kernels**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0041-5553(72)90151-6), U.S.S.R. Comput. Math. Math. Phys. 12 (1972), No.6, 227-243 (1973). [ZBL0268.45019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0268.45019).

[2] *Malinovskii, Ju.G.*, [**Asymptotic behaviour of the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of integral operators with $\delta$-type kernels**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0041-5553(73)90033-5), U.S.S.R. Comput. Math. Math. Phys. 13(1973), No.5, 32-44 (1974). [ZBL0289.45022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0289.45022).

**Note:** These are the only two papers (in English) that  I could find on this topic. **If there is any more literature related to these kind of asymptotic expansions please let me know.**

Comment: Erm... Are you claiming that the Sturm-Liouville operator $f\mapsto (pf')'$ with positive smooth $p$ (I assume that $a>0$) has no eigenfunctions with the Dirichlet boundary conditions on $[0,1]$? That sounds fishy, doesn't it?

Comment: @fedja You are totally correct (as usual). But I cannot tame these eigenfunctions into satisfying the boundary conditions. According to Mathemtica, the solution of $(pf')' = \lambda_2 f$ is $f(x) = c_1 I_0(4\sqrt{(x+a)\lambda_2} + c_2 K_0(4\sqrt{(x+a)\lambda_2}$ (modified Besel functions), but I cannot find $\lambda_2,c_1,c_2$ so as to make $f(0)=f(1)=0$ while $f(x)$ is real.

Comment: $\lambda_2$ is necessarily negative, so your arguments in the formula written are purely imaginary (and the coefficients complex).

Comment: @fedja Yes, I noticed that much. In particular $I_0(\mathrm i x) = J_0(x)$ which is real. However $K_0(\mathrm i x)$ is complex, and I don't see how a constant complex coefficient can make it real.... unless $c_2 = 0$, in which case we must require $J_0(4\sqrt{a|\lambda_2|}) = J_0(4\sqrt{(1 + a)|\lambda_2|}) = 0$, which I think cannot be simultaneously met. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: ... which I think cannot be simultaneously met by $\lambda_2$ unless $a$ is very specific

Comment: Well, if you have a complex solution, its conjugate must be a solution too, so your formula is a bit incomplete.

Comment: @fedja So you are saying that $f(x) = c_1 I_0(4\sqrt{(x+a)\lambda_2} + c_2 K_0(4\sqrt{(x+a)\lambda_2}$ is not the general solution?

Comment: It may be the general solution, but the way it is written is certainly utterly confusing. What I know for sure is that there are two linearly independent real solutions to any second order linear equation with non-degenerate coefficient at $f''$ and it is a bit hard to see them in this crazy form with imaginary arguments. To figure out what's going on, I need to refresh my memory about all those fancy special function representations and it is one of my least favorite topics :-).

Comment: @fedja It's the form that Mathematica returns. Numerical computation is in agreement with theory of course (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152064/534). But there should be an analytic expression for the eigenfunctions that makes it clear that they are real.